# Duplicate question - glitch

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

Today I asked a question about Bower and Polymer. However, when I pressed on the button to post my question I saw an error message, so I pressed the button again. This also gave me an error, so I decided to try my luck later.

A few minutes ago, I logged in and saw that, unbeknownst to me, I had posted two questions. One of them was actually answered, and the other marked as duplicate.

My issue is: We mark as duplicate when a question already has been asked and has an answer. This was clearly a glitch, and the questions has two candidates for an answer but not a definitive one yet.

I would like to know your opinion. This glitch costed me 2 reputation points.

Edit: Actually, as noted by @Glorfindel, I gained my rep back when I deleted the question.

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925142/polymer-and-bower)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925131/polymer-and-bower) - deleted now.

Comment: In one forum I've seen, the server load was so bad that you could post the same thing as many as a dozen times in a row and all you'd get would be a mod deleting all but one and forgetting about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a question with downvotes on it, you will [gain back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/295232) the reputation you lost. (The same holds true for upvotes, of course - you'll lose the reputation you gained from them.) To me, it seems you already have your reputation back as I don't see any '-2' on your [Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2917873/edward?tab=reputation).

A separate 'duplicate reason' doesn't seem useful to me. The situation you describe rarely happens, and, contrary to what many users think, having a question marked as duplicate isn't a problem *in itself*, i.e. it will not impose any penalties even if it happens repeatedly.

Comment: I just noticed. Thanks! My issue is still the same. SO should allow an option to vote to close a question as duplicate due to glitch or something.

Comment: What would that help? The downvote is separate from the close votes, and you don't lose any reputation from close votes.

Comment: I guess you are right, I do however think that the reason for casting a vote for closing a question would be more accurate were we given that option.

Comment: @Edward Why? Does the term "duplicate" and the explanation not pertain to this situation? To me it seems to fit exactly. Stack Overflow has even accounted for this specific situation. Usually the target question has to have an answer, but in the case of duplicates by the same asker, there is no such limitation.

Comment: @TinyGiant, I can help but to agree with you. Thanks for taking the time to give us your opinion.