# Post the question twice and losing points

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

This happened to me last night.

I had a question, I clicked on the post question, review question, clicked again...nothing happened, it got stuck. So I pressed F5 after a few minutes to refresh the page. Then I clicked on the post question, review the question again and clicked... Then the question was posted twice.

Problems:

1. I received negative points, which is quite unfair in this case.
2. Both questions were marked as duplicates, I understand one, but both? They were referencing one to another.

Apparently, this happened before to another user: [Duplicate question - glitch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338852/duplicate-question-glitch)

Comment: but I would be nice to fix this bug

Comment: @yivi I assume OP means the bug with double posting. Yes, ideally, we don't want it to happen but I do not think we can ensure it. There are all sorts of problems that can happen. Sometimes it is the site's fault because you post and you get an error (I've had that happen) but other times it might even be the network or something else. I once double posted an answer by accident because I got confused with many tabs open. I don't think the site can account for all possibilities of posting twice and all possible errors. Honestly, what happened here is best case scenario.

Comment: Can't you just delete the duplicate question? I would expect the negative points to go away if you delete it. Also, keep in mind that people spend time on reading your questions and trying to answer them. While your case was a glitch, there might be others with intentions to post duplicates. It is hard(and frankly not communities' job) to realize the motive. They want to clean the site content so others find it more useful. I would say do not take it personal and simply delete the duplicate. I do not expect the glitch to happen often to worry either.

Comment: @Ehsan Deleting downvoted post will restore your reputation but will still count towards the question ban.

Comment: @Iria If such glitch happens, the best you can do is to delete duplicated post as fast as you can, before it starts collecting down votes. Someone suggested that on one of your duplicate posts, but you haven't done this. Now it is down voted. Suggestion still stands, delete that before it gets more.

Answer (score 13):

Your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885138/inheritance-in-json) was voted a duplicate of your second question. This is a somewhat common practice, since it sometimes happens that a user posts twice. When that happens to questions, the easiest way to handle it is to close one against the other, since that at least ensures the question asker will get one set of answers, instead of splitting relevant answers (and comments) between the two post.

Your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885156/inheritance-in-json) was closed as a duplicate of [How do I parse a JSON string to a C# object using inheritance / polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311635/how-do-i-parse-a-json-string-to-a-c-sharp-object-using-inheritance-polymorphis) by a gold badge user<sup>1</sup>. I would *assume* that contains an answer to the coding you have, although I'm not an expert.

<sup>1</sup> Gold badge users have posted significant contribution towards a tag. As such, they should have seen many of the posts on that tag and are thus trusted by the system to single handedly close questions as duplicate.